# determining the max resolution that a computer can do HEVC encodings to?

Tags: laptop, video, graphics-card, h.265, gopro

I have two different computers, each with v1.2.2.649 of GoPro Player. On one of them I can export 360° HEVC video with a resolution of 5.6K without issue. On the other one I cannot - the max resolution I can encode to is 4K. If I try to select a higher resolution with HEVC it switches to CineForm.

Both computers support HVEC hardware acceleration.

The one that *does* encode 5.6K resolution has an Intel Iris Plus Graphics adapter (Intel Core i7-1065G7). The one that only encodes up to 4K has an Intel UHD Graphics 620 adapter (Intel Core i7-10610U).

So I guess in this case experimentation has revealed the max resolution I can encode HEVC videos at BUT if I were in the market for a new computer could I find out what the maximum resolution the computer supports for HEVC encoding is?

https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/encode-and-decode-capabilities-for-7th-generation-intel-core-processors-and-newer.html mentions which Intel cards support HEVC encoding but it doesn't mention the max resolution that they'll do that encoding at.

Comment: What are the CPUs of the two computers?

Comment: @harrymc - I added the CPU's to my question. The one that goes only up to 4K has a Intel Core i7-10610U. The one that goes up to 5.6K is a Intel Core i7-1065G7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specification for the
[Intel Core i7-10610U](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/201896/intel-core-i710610u-processor-8m-cache-up-to-4-90-ghz.html)
include this:

[image]

The specification for the
[Intel Core i7-1065G7](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/196597/intel-core-i7-1065g7-processor-8m-cache-up-to-3-90-ghz.html)
include this:

[image]

You can see from the above that
the Intel Core i7-10610U is indeed limited to 4K,
while the Intel Core i7-1065G7 can do 5K.

The way to ensure that the CPU you buy can do encoding at 5K,
is to consult the specifications before buying.

Note that these specifications are for the built-in GPU.
One way to avoid such a limitation is by adding another GPU card
that is less limited (if possible).